# Why is it that throw new exception does not echo the message?

Tags: php, error-handling, throw

I have been trying throw  new exception in my php function, but it does not echo the error the message. I could have used the regular echo  instead, but I really want to see the difference. please tell me what's wrong with this code.

```
function searchMovie($movieName){
      if (!isset($movieName))
        throw new Exception('missing movie name');
      //execute
      //return something here
}
 //call the function
 echo searchMovie('iron man'); //this gives a result.

 echo searchMovie(); //this does not echo the 'missing movie name'
```

Thanks. Any help for a noob like me will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this

```
function searchMovie($movieName){
  if (!isset($movieName))
  { 
    throw new Exception('missing movie name');
  //execute
  //return something here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an exception is only part of the process. You also have to `catch` it and attempt to either recover or display the error to the user in a meaningful way